# titanium touchstart, touchend do not carry on when moving between views

Tags: titanium

So i am using titanium, and the touchstart event doesn't seem t fire when moving between views.

To give an example, say i have a button on my page. The button has a touchstart event that, say, makes it twice as big.
Now if i touch directly on the button then hooray! The button is twice as big.

However, if i touch elsewhere on the screen (on the background, say), and then drag my finger to the button, then the button is not twice as big. In fact, nothing happens.

Is there some problem with the way titanium handles touchevents between views? Am i meant to set or reset some value for this to occur?

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't have thought touchstart would have worked that way myself.  Touchstart to me would be the location that I initially started touching.  If you are dragging down to the button, I would expect that to be a drag event at that point and the touchstart was already over.  Have you tried handling the touchmove event as well?

Comment: i gave it a whirl, but in initial testing it stopped responding after i'd left the initial view used